# Textarea component in flash cs3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs3

i have this htm file that i want to display it in textarea component in flash application.
But i had this error when debugging the movie
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
```

loader.load(new URLRequest("meeting minutes - thesis - 1.htm"));
addChild(loader);

any solutions please!

Answer (score 0):

The [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html) class if for displaying visual content like another swf. file or an image. 
What you want to use is the [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) class.

Quick'n'dirty example:

```
new URLLoader(new URLRequest("meeting minutes - thesis - 1.htm")).addEventListener(Event.Complete,function(e:Event){
                yourTextAreaComponentInstance.text = String(e.target.data);
            });
```

You want to look at the [example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#includeExamplesSummary) to write nicely (handle errors/etc.)